# Prolog encoded integers, less/2(X, Y) predicate

Tags: prolog

A question states the following:

In Prolog, non-negative integers can be encoded as numerals given by 0 and its successors (with, for example, the numeral s(s(s(0))) encoding 3).

```
numeral(0).
numeral(s(X)) :- numeral(X).
```

Define the predicate less/2(X, Y) that holds when X and Y are numerals encoding non-negative integers x and y such that x < y. For example,

```
?- less(0, s(0)).
yes.
?- less(s(s(0)), s(s(0))).
no.
```

I have been able to come up with a solution for this question, however, it suffers from a limitation. Here is my solution:

```
less(X, s(X)) :- numeral(X).
less(X, Z) :- less(X, Y), less(Y, Z).
```

This solution correctly outputs a `yes` for inputs that satisfy this predicate. However, for inputs that expect a `no`, this solution seems to enter an endless recursion of some sort, and the program just keeps running, rather than outputting a `no`.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like this:

```
less(0, s(Y)) :- numeral(Y).
less(s(X), s(Y)) :- less(X, Y).

?- less(0, s(0)).
true.

?- less(s(s(0)), s(s(0))).
false.
```

The idea is that `0` is less than any `s(Y)`, where `Y` is a numeral. If `X` is not `0`, then `X` is `s(X')`, and `X = s(X')` is less than `Y = s(Y')` iff `X'` is less than `Y'`.

This does only work if both `X` and `Y` are numerals. If X is not a numeral then it will get stuck somewhere in the recursion and "returns" false. Same for `Y`, except that there need to be a test at the end if the rest of `Y` is a numeral.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
less2(X, s(X)) :- numeral(X).
less2(X, s(Y)) :- less2(X,Y).
```

Seems to work for me; your solution could recurse endlessly though, because if there exists no value of Y between X and Z it will simply try everything under the sun.